# Is there is any way to store data via Firebase SDK on device only?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I checked Firebase Android SDK [offline capabilities documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html) and cannot find any info if there is a possibility to store data without server synchronization. I know that the main idea is to have consistent database across apps and server but for example [Parse SDK has a way to store local objects only](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/).

Is there is a way to store local data only (like in Parse) or I need to use another solution?

EDIT: I am not looking for alternatives, just want to know if this is somehow possible with Firebase Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database is primarily a cloud-hosted database that also handles intermittent and medium term lack of connectivity. While your device has no network connectivity, it will be queueing all your local changes. It will continue to function, but the queue performance will deteriorate (slowly) with the length of that queue.

If you're looking for an offline-first database, you might want to look at other options. Recommendations for which one is preferred are off-topic on Stack Overflow though.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I am aware of great support for offline mode but just wondering if can store purely local objects besides standard behaviour.  I'm not looking for alternatives I know possible solutions :) Are there any plans to support local database in the future like it is in the Parse SDK?

Comment: We're aware that there is a demand for this type of functionality. But as usual I can't comment on roadmap or timelines.